# Is every reductive group scheme etale locally trivial?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $S$ be a scheme over a field $k$, and let $G$ be a reductive group scheme over $S$. Let us call it *trivial*, if it is a pull-back of a group scheme over $k$ via the structure morphism $S\to k$. Is it always true that $G$ becomes trivial after a certain etale base change $S'\to S$? I am willing to assume that $S$ is smooth if needed.

Comment: The question looks natural, but it would be interesting to know a little more about the background or the implications.

Comment: If you look at SGA 3, Prop XIX.6.1, it is essentially shown that any reductive group over any base is split after a finite etale base change. So if you allow extensions of scalars of $k$ as well, then what you need follows. 

Comment: Sorry, it appears as if the Proposition does not guarantee you a *finite* etale base change, though I would be surprised if this weren't true.

Comment: I have been informed by the esteemed BCnrd that my previous comment was too optimistic. In fact, in his paper 'Groups over $\mathbb{Z}$', B. Gross has shown the existence of non-split simply-connected semi-simple groups over $\mathbb{Q}$ that have reductive models over $\mathbb{Z}$. In particular, these models can only split after a non-finite etale base-change over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Answering the question of Jim, if the statement is correct, then reductive group schemes over $S$ are classified by $H^1_{et}(S, Aut_G)$, right? 

Comment: Now I see what the problem is. But the statement about cohomological classification of reductive group schemes is still correct, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reductive groups schemes over $S$ are classified by $H^1_{fpqc}(S,Aut_G)$, see SGA 3 Exp. XXIV.

Comment: You can indeed replace $fpqc$ by $et$, see SGA 3 Exp. XXIV Cor. 1.18

Comment: Note that SGA3 has its own definition of reductive. The geometric fibers have to be connected.